# Deprecate custom attribute in a custom view

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

Is it possible to deprecate a custom attribute?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
       <!-- {@deprecated Use foobar instead.} -->
      <attr name="my_title" format="string"/>
      <attr name="title_text_size" format="dimension"/>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Regards,
Scott.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mark a resource in my android project as deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683787/can-i-mark-a-resource-in-my-android-project-as-deprecated)

Comment: Thanks mate, this helped.